# Страница записи показывает неверный контент

Tags: wordpress

Делаю [сайт](http://malginovdesign.ru/bastion-u/). Первый раз вижу такое: wp на странице одиночной записи показывает не тот контент. При чем один и тот же, от другой записи(на данный момент это "Юридическое абонентское обслуживание ИП и юр.лиц"). Если удалить ту запись - показывается другая, но тоже неправильная. Закономерностей между показываемыми записями не нашел

Код single.php:

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section class="hero-header cw" <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
 style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'full' ); ?>)"
<?php endif ?>>
<div class="wrapper1200 flex_c-c">
 <h1 class="post_title font36 ta-c margin_h0"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
</div>
</section>
<div class="breadcrumbs dark_bg_color">
 <div class="wrapper1200">
  <a href="/salus" class="__link">Главная</a>
  <span class="sep">/</span> 
  <span class="__current"><?php the_title(); ?>
  </span> 
 </div>
</div>
<div class="post-text font18px wrapper1200">
 <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<div class="single_help_request">
 <div class="wrapper1200 flex_c-c">
  <div class="help_request__title font24 segoeuiregular">Есть вопросы?<br>Нужна помощь?</div>
  <div class="button-container">
   <div class="pre segoeuiregular">
    Бесплатная юридическая консультация
   </div>
   <button class="form_trigger btn agorablack uppercase">Получить консультацию<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема найдена. Итак, первое - старайтесь не использовать `query_posts();` и, второе - используйте `wp_reset_query();` при выводе постов. Моя ошибка как раз в этом. Код header.php:

```html
...
<?php $cats = get_categories('child_of=3&order=asc');
    foreach ($cats as $cat) {
     $cat_id= $cat->term_id;
     echo "<h4 class='font14 agorablack'>".$cat->name."</h4>";
     query_posts("cat=$cat_id&posts_per_page=100&orderby=name&order=asc");
     if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
     <div class="work_item font18">
      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="menu-toggle">
       <span class="item_dot agorablack">·</span> <?php the_title(); ?>
      </a>
     </div>
     <?php 
     endwhile; 
     endif;
     [wp_reset_postdata();]
     ?>
     <?php } ?> 
...
```